# Convert the http response from JSON objects to Typescript class

Tags: json, spring-boot, angular2-services

I have a spring boot web api running on the backend and i'm trying to cosume it from an angular 2 webApp, the HTTP response is like the following

[image: HTTP response]

what I'm trying to do is convert the JSON object received as response to a defined Typescript class so I can use in my application

[image: HTTPService.ts]

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of your code. Instead, add a minimal, testable example or  a jsfiddle, codepen, etc. to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 uses subscribe method. Try this:

```
this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/new/.json?limit=10').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    this.posts = data.data.children;
});
```

Used in Ionic 2 demo: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/